# WordPress: How to enable or disable taxonomies?

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to allow a administrator to enable and disable taxonomies in WordPress through a click on a check-box or so in the dashboard.

The result should be, that I can list all taxonomies with state 'enabled' in the front-end.

I don't use standard categories but a lot of different custom taxonomies.

Does anyone know how to solve this? Is there a plugin or a way to do this from scratch?

Thanks in advance,
Kev

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a custom taxonomy field with [Advanced Custom Fields](https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/).